# Apps stopped unexpectedly when going back with action bar

Tags: java, android

I have been reading different questions and answers regarding this but I still don't get a clue. I am really sorry as I know this question is repeated but I really need help :(

Whenever I press the back in the action bar, the apps stopped unexpectedly.

```
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591): Process: com.FYP.undergraduate, PID: 10591
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.FYP.undergraduate/com.FYP.undergraduate.ChooseSubject}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at com.FYP.undergraduate.ChooseSubject.onCreate(ChooseSubject.java:35)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
05-05 01:39:03.685: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    ... 11 more
05-05 01:39:06.175: I/Process(10591): Sending signal. PID: 10591 SIG: 9
05-05 01:39:06.340: W/ApplicationPackageManager(11234): getCSCPackageItemText()
```

This is the partial coding of the class, ChooseSubject.java.

```
package com.FYP.undergraduate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ChooseSubject extends Activity 
{
    String loginID;
    ProgressBar spinner1;
    int role;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_subject);
        setupActionBar();
        loginID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("LOGINID");
        role = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ROLE");
        new MyGetSubjectClass().execute();
        spinner1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() 
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
        {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.choose_subject, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: What is line 35 in this class? (see the error: *com.FYP.undergraduate.ChooseSubject.onCreate(ChooseSubject.java:35)*)

Comment: Line 35 is "loginID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("LOGINID");"

Comment: so there it is. either getIntent() is null or getExtras() on the intent is null.Now yo figure out the rest.

Comment: ok.. Thanks, I will try to search more about these.

Comment: as I understand it, returning to an activity using the back button will mean that the intent no longer exists (unless you specifically code it that way) - if that is correct it would make more sense in this case to store your string in shared preferences

Comment: @lucas , So rather than using intent, I should be storing what the user key in with SharedPreferences?

Comment: Does the scenario is: another activity is displayed, you press the back up indicator, return to `ChooseSubject` and the app crashes?

Comment: @Fllo, Yes. It happens for all activities...

Comment: When you return to `ChooseSubject` do you do an Intent with startActivity?

Comment: startActivity? Do you mean onCreate()? I am sorry, I am a college student doing my school project....

Comment: No problem. No, I meant when you return to `ChooseSubject` do you call another Intent to call this previous activity from the "up" activity? I don't know how you do this, however call `finish` in the "up" activity will destroy it and automatically display `ChooseSubject` activity without reinitialize it.. (see the first part on my below answer).

Comment: Yes, I use intent to start a new activity.  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important thing, I'd suggest you to not use `navigateUpFromSameTask` in Android, because there is [a known bug on 4.1 and higher](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58520). In the case of "up" activity, **you can simply call `finish()` method to destroy the current activity** and automatically return to the parent activity:

```
case android.R.id.home:
    this.finish(); // the "up" activity will be destroyed
    return true;
```

I suspect that you do another `Intent` when you are in "up" activity to return to `ChooseSubject` then the activity has no datas from this new Intent, because normally you do this to call `ChooseSubject` activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(PreviousActivity.this, ChooseSubject.class);
// pass the datas
i.putString("LOGINID", loginIdStringValue);
// then, call startActivity method
startActivity(i);
```

And in the case of you are calling `startActivity` again to (re)launch `ChooseSubject` class, you haven't pass any datas. The `onCreate` and `getIntent` are called when the activity is displayed for the first time. When you have another activity which is launched, you can just return to the previous activity without called these methods again, with `finish()`.

Maybe you should store the value sent to avoid a null exception. When you look at the Documentation about [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), you can see that `onCreate` is called only if the activity is no longer visible and another app needs memory. However, according to the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html):

> The system uses the Bundle instance state to save information about each View object in your activity layout (such as the text value entered into an EditText object). So, if your activity instance is destroyed and recreated, the state of the layout is restored to its previous state with no code required by you.

Then, you can store the values as follows:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the datas
    savedInstanceState.putString("SAVED_LOGINID", getIntent().getExtras().getString("LOGINID"));
    savedInstanceState.putInt("SAVED_ROLE", getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ROLE"));

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

[This method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) is called before placing the activity in such a background state. And you can retrieve these values inside `onCreate` which uses a `Bundle` as parameter like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_subject);

    // Check the state of the activity bundle
    if(savedInstanceState != null) { // the activity has already be created
         loginID = savedInstanceState.getString("SAVED_LOGINID");
         role = savedInstanceState.getInt("SAVED_ROLE");
    } else { // the activity is displayed for the 1st time
         loginID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("LOGINID");
         role = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ROLE");
    }
    //...
}
```

In the case of you need the values inside other activities, a solution might be using [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to store it on the device, see also [Saving Persistent State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) section. However, you have some other features as you can see on [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

It might resolve your issue and I hope this helps.
Let me know if you need more information about that.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problems!! Thank you~